# Is the aliasing formula for DFT a folklore result?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, math-history, fourier-transform

The aliasing formula for the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) can be written succinctly as
$$G_k^N=\sum_{l=-\infty}^\infty G_{k+Nl}$$
where $G_k^N:=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}g(\frac{iT}{N})\exp[-j2\pi\frac{ki}{N}]$ for a $T$-periodic function $g$ with absolutely convergent Fourier series and Fourier coefficients $G_k:=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tg(\tau)\exp[-j2\pi\frac{k}{T}\tau]d\tau$.

Potts, D. and Steidl, G. **Fast summation at nonequispaced knots by NFFTs**. SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 24, 2013-2037, 2003 (can be downloaded from [here](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/doc.php)) for example state it somewhat less succinct as Theorem 2.1 (Aliasing formula) without proof as
$$\hat{g}_k=c_k(g)+\sum_{\begin{array}{c}r\in\mathbb Z\\r\neq 0\end{array}} c_{k+rn}(g)$$
where the Fourier coefficients of $g$ have been named $c_k(g)$ instead of $G_k$ and $\hat{g}_k$ was described as an approximation of $c_k(g)$ using the trapezoidal quadrature rule instead of calling it the DFT $G_k^N$.

The aliasing formula is easy to prove (just plug the Fourier series for $g$
into the formula for $G_k^N$), but I never saw any reference explicitly proving it. In fact, I even had trouble finding a reference (like the one given above) stating the aliasing formula as an explicit formula, instead of just describing it in informal words when explaining the need for a low-pass filter to avoid aliasing during sampling.

One indication that I am not the only one having problems finding an explicit (textbook) reference for this formula is the statement of the formula in Theorem 2.8 of the thesis by S. Kunis **Nonequispaced FFT - Generalisation and Inversion** from 2006 (can be downloaded from [here](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/doc.php)) without a reference to a source, while many other theorems and lemmas in the same chapter have explicit references to a source.

The strange thing about the aliasing formula is that it is not really difficult (neither to state nor to prove). Hence I wonder why I can't find it in textbooks, and whether it is really a folklore result (whatever that means)? After all, it is used in an informal sense in some (engineering) textbooks.